# Location of graph plotting routes on Flask boilerplate

Tags: python, flask, flask-restful, boilerplate

I just downloaded a [This](https://appseed.us/admin-dashboards/flask-dashboard-sleek) flask boilerplate but I have never used any of it. My intentional is to use it to create a data dashboard which should display graphs on html page. My question is where do I create my routes for plotting code or I need to create another file app.py for plotting routes? Here is how the boilerplate structure looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this project is using Blueprints, you should have a read [here](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/blueprints/),
You can add more routes as directed in the documentation.

---